# installing Pandas on a server without internet connection

Tags: python, pandas, pip, dependencies

I'm trying to install the pandas package on a server without a connection to the internet, but I'm having problems installing the dependencies

On my machine connected to the internet, I've tried to download all the packages using .whl following the requirements:

```
numpy==1.18.1
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2019.3
```

then, first I've downloaded everything on my online machine using:

```
pip download -r requirements.txt -d pandas_dependecies
```

and then I sent pandas_dependecies to my offline machine and ran the following code:

```
pip install -r pandas_dependecies/requirements.txt --no-index --find-links pandas_dependecies
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy>=1.18.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy>=1.18.1
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Easiest way is download the whole [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/?modal=nucleus-commercial) and install it on your machine.

Comment: @QuangHoang, but can I install it using anaconda in my online machine and send the package to my offiline server? Because I can't install anything that need internet connection on my server

Comment: What is the operating system and python version on the online and offline machine?

Comment: @FlyingTeller, operating system on the offline machine = Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS; operating system on online machine = Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS; python offline machine = Python 3.8.10; python online machine: Python 3.7.6.

Comment: Ooooooh, I see now! I was getting the cp37 .whl file when I was downloading the files on my online machine. I uploaded the python on my online machine and worked perfectly!!

Comment: @vini8cs Platforms (processor architecture, OS, Python version and 32/64 bitness) must be the same or very close. Ubuntu 20.04.3 vs Ubuntu 20.04.4 are ok. Python 3.8.6 vs Python 3.8.10 are ok. Python 3.7.6 vs Python 3.8.10 are not ok. You need to use the same Python (either 3.7 or 3.8) on both hosts.